# Data Driven testing with cucumber protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

Lets say I have a scenario in my demo.feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Gather and load all submenus
Given I will login using <username> and <password>
When I will click all links
Examples :
| username | password |
| user1 | pass1 |
| use2 | pass2 |
```

lets say i have a file called users.json

How can i get those usernames and passwords from that external file to my demo.feature ?
Can I catch the file by passing parameters to my npm script like below ?
npm run cucumber -- --params.environment.file=usernames.json

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having the login step access that json file within the step definition. Just make sure not to check it into the repo and instead always expect it to be in a location but only locally and not in the repository.

Doing the above is useful for a couple of reasons:
- An engineer running your tests does not need to know that a param must be passed in from the command line
- The code is self-descriptive in that step as to how it logs in
- You can add better error handling
- You can use multiple user files if needs be by having hooks define paths etc based on tags